# How to paginate more than 2000 records in datatables? MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables

I need your help.
Currently my query returns more than **2000 records**, after obtaining the records from sql server through a stored procedure I send them to the table (**I use the DataTables library 1.10.19**) and it is when it begins to form the table and the corresponding pagination the problem is that It takes more than **30 seconds** or more to show the content in the table, how can I do it so that it only shows the results that the user sees (**10 records per page**) and calculates the other pages that it would have if the user advances to the next records and bring me the following 10 records or how would the page be?.
This is my code:
**Controller:**

```
 public JsonResult Get_Pacientes(int IdEstatus)
{
 List<Paciente> l = new List<Paciente>(Get_RowsPac(IdEstatus));
 var jsonResult = Json(new { success = true, lcontenedor= l}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
                    return jsonResult;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
   function ObtieneListaEmp(id) {
            $('#fader').css('display', 'block');
            var EnviaDatos =
            {
                //"e.CVE_EMPLEADO": $('#NOMINA').val(),
                "IdEstatus": id,

            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '../Empleado/EmpleadosXEstatus',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(EnviaDatos),
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#fader').css('display', 'none');

                    if (response.success) {

                        AgregaTablaEmpPacTest(); //this function adds the table header

                        var data = [];
                        
                        data = response.lcontenedor;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            //aqui va la tarea
                            $('#tbl').DataTable({
                                data: data,
                                deferRender: true,
                                "columns": [
                                    //{ "data": "CLAVE_AFILIACION" },
                                    { // render //clave afilacion
                                        "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                            return "<a href=\"#\" onclick='LlamaRegistro(" + '"' + data.CLAVE_AFILIACION + '"' + ")'>" + data.CLAVE_AFILIACION + "</a>";
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { "data": "NOMINA" },
                                    {
                                        data: null,
                                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                                            return row.NOMBRE + ' ' + row.APELLIDO_PAT + ' ' + row.APELLIDO_MAT;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { "data": "TELEFONO_CASA" },
                                    { "data": "CELULAR" },
                                    { "data": "SECRETARIA" },
                                    { "data": "DIRECCION" },
                                    { "data": "PUESTO" },
                                    { "data": "EDAD" },
                                    { "data": "OBSERVACION" },
                                    { "data": "FECHA_SEG" },
                                    { "data": "DESC_ESTATUS_EVO" },
                                    { "data": "FECHA_PRUEBA" },
                                    { "data": "FECHA_RESULTADO" },
                                    { "data": "LUGAR_DE_EXP" },
                                    { "data": "DESC_ESTATUS_PRU" },
                                    { "data": "FECHAINICIO_INC" },
                                    { "data": "DIASINCAPACIDAD_INC" },
                                    { "data": "FECHAFIN_INC" },
                                    //{ "data": "FECHAFIN_INC" },
                                    { // render IMPRIMIR
                                        "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                            return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-secondary fa fa-print C_Imprimir\">";
                                        }
                                    },
                                ],
                                "columnDefs": [
                                    {
                                        "targets": [3],
                                        "visible": false,
                                        "searchable": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "targets": [4],
                                        "visible": false,
                                        "searchable": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                                buttons: [
                                    //'copy', 'csv',
                                    'excel', {
                                        extend: 'pdf',
                                        orientation: 'landscape',
                                        pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                                    }, {
                                        extend: 'print'//,
                                        //messageTop: 'Lista de Empleados Registrados' + response.lOrdenesTrabajo[0].NOMBRE_PROV
                                        , text: 'Imprimir'
                                    }
                                ],
                                "order": [7, 'desc'],//ordernar por fecha de menor a mayor
                                "language": {
                                    "scrollX": true,
                                    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                                    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                                    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                                    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                                    "sUrl": "",
                                    "sInfoThousands": ",",
                                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                                    "oPaginate": {
                                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                                        "sLast": "Último",
                                        "sNext": "Siguiente",
                                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                                    },
                                    "oAria": {
                                        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }, 50);
                        //AgregaTablaEmpPac(response.lcontenedor);


                    }
                    else {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $('#fader').css('display', 'none');
                    alert('Ocurrio un Error Inesperado.' + $('#Datos_ID_FechaIn').val());
                }
            })

        };
```

Comment: Maybe do multiple ajax calls and retrieve rows chunk by chunk?

Comment: One approach is to use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) - it sends subsets of data, but in this case the server takes over responsibility for paging, sorting,and filtering, based on a user's actions in the data table. Another (maybe) is to use the [scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extension. (I've used server-side, but not the scroller extension.)

Answer (score 0):

i have a sameproblem, i use this type of code to just send the number of records desired:

```
[DataContract]
public class Course
{
    [DataMember] public string[] UrlsCourse;
    [DataMember] public string BackgroundImage;
    [DataMember] public string KeyWords;
    [DataMember] public string TitleCourse;
    [DataMember] public string[] stats;
    [DataMember] public string description;

    public Course(string[] urlsCourse, string backgroundImage, string keyWords, string titleCourse, string[] stats, string description)
    {
        UrlsCourse = urlsCourse;
        BackgroundImage = backgroundImage;
        KeyWords = keyWords;
        TitleCourse = titleCourse;
        this.stats = stats;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class SearchCourses
{
    [DataMember] public readonly int maxRecords;
    [DataMember] public int maxRecordsPerPage;
    [DataMember] public int currentRecord;
    [DataMember] public int currentPage;
    [DataMember] public int maxPages;
    [DataMember] public int[] minmax;
    [DataMember] public int maxRecordsSent;
    [DataMember] public int currentmaxLinks;
    [DataMember] public Course[] currentDatas;
    [DataMember] public string[] categories;
    public Course[] search;
    public string[] courses;
    public int maxLinks;
    public SearchCourses(string[] courses, int maxRecordsPerPage = 10, int currentPage = 1, int currentRecord = 0, int maxLinks = 9)
    {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;

        this.maxRecordsPerPage = maxRecordsPerPage;
        this.currentRecord = currentRecord;
        this.courses = courses;
        this.maxRecords = courses.Length;
        this.maxLinks = maxLinks;
        this.search = courses.Select(r => getRecord(r.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None))).ToArray();
        categories = this.search.Select(c => c.KeyWords.Split('-')[0].Trim()).Distinct().ToArray();
        currentDatas = search.Take(maxRecordsPerPage).ToArray();

        maxRecordsSent = maxRecords;

        maxPages = maxRecordsSent / maxRecordsPerPage + 1;
        this.currentPage = 1;

        maxPages = maxRecordsSent / maxRecordsPerPage + 1;
        currentmaxLinks = maxLinks > maxPages ? maxPages : maxLinks;
        minmax = new int[] { 1, currentmaxLinks };

    } 

    public string GetJSON()
    {
        string json;



        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SearchCourses));
            js.WriteObject(ms, this);
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return json;
    }
```

its a server which gives different lists of courses, so i keep the last search in "search" but just send the desired datas in currentDatas, (i serialize only the currentDatas not the search with GetJSON() method).

i have a bookmark with number of pages...and so on..

i manage the bookmark dislplying the max number of pages (here i have 9 links bookmark), and i manage buttons next and forward page ..and so on..